# Usage of "elder" and "eldest" in degrees of comparison

Tags: word-usage, comparatives, superlative-degree

If one has two elder brothers, is it OK to say "My eldest brother is this and the second eldest is that"?

Comment: Use 'oldest and 'second oldest' and ask people who say the latter is illogical and therefore unacceptable how they explain away 'second best'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's fine, but other people evidently disagree. I found discussion of the topic of whether "second eldest" is a correct turn of expression in a court case, actually:

> It is said, "second eldest" is not grammar; there can only be one "eldest". I do not agree in that. I suppose that it would be good grammar to say "A, B and C, are the three oldest men in the parish."

(Thellusson *v.* Rendlesham [1858-59], in *[The English Reports,](https://books.google.com/books?id=mCAwAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA183)* Volume XI: House of Lords, Containing House of Lords Cases (Clark's), Volumes 7 to 11)

Comment: "Second oldest" is also common, as in the idiom "World's second oldest profession". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_second_oldest_profession

Comment: Expressions like 'second fastest', 'second highest' and of course 'second best' are common. I'd choose 'second oldest' though.

Answer (score 0):

An “elder” brother must be older than the speaker. An “eldest” brother should be the oldest child, but it can be used by a sister talking about the oldest of her brothers, who are all younger than her. In that case “the oldest of my brothers” would be clearer. If a family has three boys, then boy #2 is literally the oldest brother of boy #1, but boy #1 calling him “my oldest brother” would be confusing.

Answer (score -1):

*Eldest* is a superlative, while *elder* is a [comparative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_(grammar)). While you have two elder brothers, there can only be one eldest brother.

If you say,

> My elder brother lives in Los Angeles, while my eldest brother lives in Chicago.

then the hearer would know that you have at least two elder brothers and that the oldest lives in Chicago.

Comment: I wouldn't contrast "my eldest brother" with "my elder brother" like this. The expression "my elder brother" is typically understood as meaning something like "my brother who is older than me". So when you start a sentence with "my elder brother", it's not clear that you have two brothers and that you are talking about the younger one.

Comment: I don't see how there is anything wrong with the expression "second eldest". Superlatives are fairly commonly prefixed with "second" to indicate "the next-to-greatest".

Comment: Related: [Can the eldest sibling of three males call his younger brother “my older brother”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137617/can-the-eldest-sibling-of-three-males-call-his-younger-brother-my-older-brother)

Comment: The specific phrase "My eldest brother is this and the second eldest is that" complicates the apparent issue into near incomprehensibility. I suggest that older/elder/eldest is vastly more complex than most of us realise, and not simply because at least a huge minority of, if not most English speakers couldn't explain it to save their lives. 

If you're sure "older/elder/eldest" isn't about number, that's fine.

In my view there is no comparison to older/elder/eldest in any other part of English, purely because this is about number… More…

Comment: Further… “Good/better/best” has nothing to do with number in English or any other language while several Central European languages do make important distinctions among one; more than one and up to five; more than five; many. (Try, for instance Czech, Polish, Slovakian, Slovenian and possibly Russian, among others.)

Answer (score -1):

Older and oldest refer to age
--> She is the oldest member of the committee.

Elder and eldest refer to seniority within a family. 
--> My eldest sister is 4 years older than me.

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to EL&U. I'm inclined to agree with your answer, but at this site we don't rely on personal opinion, we seek *authoritative answers* backed up by evidence. You can [edit] your post to add a quote from a reference book or an explanation and link to an online source. See [answer] for further guidance. :-)

Comment: The New Fowler's Modern English Usage: “**elder**. As an adj., elder is now for the most part confined to the meaning '(of two indicated persons, esp. when related) senior, of a greater age (his elder brother)'. Hence the superlative form eldest. Outside this restricted use of family seniority, elder lingers [where] elders mean[s] persons whose age is supposed to command the respect of the young,... the elder brethren of Trinity House, ..., and elder statesman. In all ordinary contexts when the comparative and superlative forms of old are called for these are, of course, older and oldest.”

Answer (score -3):

You don't have an "eldest" because there are only two. Same reason you don't have "second eldest" even. Both are your elder brothers:

the **older of the elder brothers** and **the younger of the elder brothers**.

Comment: If both brothers are older, why do you need to specify elder? *My oldest (youngest) brother* would suffice and is not ambiguous.

Comment: @JJJ Perhaps. :D

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica See Peter Selie.